# Evaluating $\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x-i} dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I would like to evaluate the integral
$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x-i} dx,$$
which I believe should be equal to $\frac{\pi}{e}$. However, I cannot reproduce this result by hand. My work is as follows: first, we evaluate the indefinite integral.

\begin{align*}
\int \frac{\sin x}{x-i} dx &= \int \frac{\sin(u+i)}{u} du \text{ where }u=x-i \\
&= \int \frac{\sin u \cos i + \cos u \sin i}{u} du \\
&= \mathrm{Si}(u) \cos i + \mathrm{Ci}(u) \sin i \\
&= \mathrm{Si}(x-i) \cosh 1 + i\mathrm{Ci}(x-i) \sinh 1 \\
\end{align*}

Then, we insert the bounds.

\begin{align*}
\int_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin x}{x-i} dx &= \mathrm{Si}(\infty-i) \cosh 1 + i\mathrm{Ci}(\infty-i) \sinh 1 \\
&\phantom{=}-\mathrm{Si}(-\infty-i) \cosh 1 - i\mathrm{Ci}(-\infty-i) \sinh 1 \\
&= \frac{\pi}{2}\cosh 1 + 0 +\frac{\pi}{2} \cosh 1 + \pi \sinh 1 \\
&= \pi (\cosh 1 + \sinh 1) \\
&= \pi e
\end{align*}

I assume I have made some mistake in manipulating the complex sine and cosine integrals, since the result would be correct if $\mathrm{Ci}(-\infty-i)$ were evaluated to $-i \pi$. However, I cannot pinpoint the error.

Comment: $u=x-i$ but you have sustituted it by $x+i$. I think that's the problem.

Comment: @Adolfo Thanks, I've fixed the signs on $i$. However, this doesn't seem to change anything.

Comment: @Adolfo No, I take that back--$\mathrm{Ci}$ appears to have a branch cut across the negative real axis, which is the source of the issue. Thanks!

Comment: Try to use contour integration and see what you get.

Answer (score 4):

Write the sin-function as the difference of two exponentials and obtain the corresponding integrals by contour integration. This gives the result:
\begin{eqnarray*}
I &=&\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\frac{1}{x-i}\sin x=\int_{-\infty
}^{+\infty }dx\frac{1}{x-i}\frac{1}{2i}\left\{ e^{ix}-e^{-ix}\right\}  \\
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\frac{1}{x-i}e^{ix} &=&2\pi ie^{-1} \\
\int_{-\infty }^{+\infty }dx\frac{1}{x-i}e^{-ix} &=&0 \\
I &=&\frac{1}{2i}2\pi ie^{-1}=\frac{\pi }{e}
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: Suppose you used the Residues Theorem in the second step.

Answer (score 3):

The mistake is simple--$\mathrm{Ci}$ has a branch cut across the negative real axis, so $\mathrm{Ci}(-\infty - i)$ should indeed evaluate to $-i \pi$ rather than $i \pi$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle\, #1 \,\right\rangle}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\, #1 \,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\, #1 \,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\dsc}[1]{\displaystyle{\color{red}{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\Li}[1]{\,{\rm Li}_{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\, #1 \,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\vphantom{\large A}\,#2\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$

\begin{align}
\color{#f00}{\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin\pars{x} \over x - \ic}\,\dd x} & =
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x\sin\pars{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x =
\Im\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{x\expo{\ic x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\dd x
\\[5mm] = & \
\Im\pars{2\pi\ic\,{\ic\expo{\ic\ic} \over \ic + \ic}} =
\color{#f00}{{\pi \over \expo{}}}
\end{align}

The integration was performed along a semi-circle in the upper half complex plane by using the Residues Theorem.

Comment: Quote: "However, I cannot pinpoint the error." How does this pinpoint the error?

Answer (score 0):

It is also possible to use integral transforms of Laplace and Fourier.

\begin{align}
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\sin{x} \over x-i}\,\mathrm{d}x&=
2\int_{0}^{\infty}{x\sin{x} \over x^{2} + 1}\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\mathcal{L}^{-1}\left[{s \over s^{2} + 1}\right](x)\mathcal{L}\left[\sin{t}\right](x)\,\mathrm{d}x\\
&=2\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\cos(x)}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}x\\
&=\frac\pi e.
\end{align}

The last step is not easy either to do in a fundamental approach but the generalized one is given here. [How can I demonstrate the following equality: $\int_0^\infty \frac{\cos(yx)}{y^{2}+\lambda^{2}}\, dy = \frac{\pi}{2\lambda}e^{-\lambda x}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3456142)
$$\frac{\pi}{2}\mathrm{e}^{-|t|} = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{\cos(xt)}{x^2+1}\mathrm{d}t.$$

Just found as well here: [What is wrong in this calculation $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\cos x}{1+x^2}dx$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002255).