# How to solve $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {sin(t)}{t^2+1} dt$?

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis, contour-integration

I'm considering here the fact that 
$$\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac {e^{iz}}{z^2+1} dz=0$$
, where $\Gamma$ is a contour defined as a semicircle  centred about the origin, of radius $R>1$, in the upper half-plane of $\mathbb{C}$, positively oriented.

Now, I think, one could express $\int\limits_{-\infty}^{\infty} \frac {sin(t)}{t^2+1} dt$ as $$\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac {sin(t)}{t^2+1} dt$$ But here's where I don't know what to do next. Would appreciate a hint.

On a side note, 
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{iz}}{z^2+1} dz\ne 0$$
, so I'm not sure what I'm not seeing here because $$\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac {e^{iz}}{z^2+1} dz=0$$, so where's the analogy?

Comment: Are you aware of the residue theorem?

Comment: Haven't studied it yet.

Comment: Wouldn't you check the oddity before start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The integrand is and odd function of $t$ and the integral is absolutely convergent, so
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t^2+1}dt=0$$
**EDIT**: Writing out the theorem longhand,
$$\begin{align}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\sin t}{t^2+1}dt&=\lim_{M\rightarrow-\infty}\int_M^0\frac{\sin t}{t^2+1}dt+\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^N\frac{\sin t}{t^2+1}dt\\
&=\lim_{M\rightarrow-\infty}\int_{-M}^0\frac{\sin(-u)}{u^2+1}(-du)+\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^N\frac{\sin u}{u^2+1}du\\
&=\lim_{M\rightarrow-\infty}-\int_0^{-M}\frac{\sin u}{u^2+1}du+\lim_{N\rightarrow\infty}\int_0^N\frac{\sin u}{u^2+1}du\\
&=-\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u^2+1}du+\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\sin u}{u^2+1}du=0\end{align}$$
Where we have used the substitution $u=-t$ in the left integral and $u=t$ in the right integral. Notice that all that was required for this proof to work was that the integrand was an odd function, the interval of integration was $(-\infty,\infty)$, although an interval of $(-a,a)$ would have worked and that the function was Riemann integrable over the interval. This theorem can reduce some perfectly horrible-looking integrals to zero with relatively little effort.

Comment: Can you please be more specific?

Comment: @sequence: if $f\in L^1(\mathbb{R})$ and $f$ is an odd function, $$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}f(x)\,dx = \color{red}{0}.$$

Comment: What is $L^1(\mathbb{R})$?

Answer (score 1):

First Solution:

From [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Example):
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{iz}}{z^2+1} dz = \frac{\pi}{e}$$

By [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{iz}}{z^2+1} dz =\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{cos z}{z^2+1} dz + i\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{sin z}{z^2+1} dz$$

In [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002255/what-is-wrong-in-this-calculation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-x1x2dx), it shows that:
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\cos z}{z^2+1} dz = \frac{\pi}{e}$$

In conclude:
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac{\sin z}{z^2+1} dz = 0$$

Alternative Solution(inspired by [the same post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1002255/what-is-wrong-in-this-calculation-int-infty-infty-frac-cos-x1x2dx)):

Because $sin(z)$ behaves not like $e^{iz}$ over the complex plane, the straightforward way to use residue theorem is invalid.

By [Euler's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_formula):
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {\sin z}{z^2+1} dz = \frac{1}{2} i (\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{-ix}}{z^2+1} dz-\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{ix}}{z^2+1} dz) $$

From [Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem#Example):
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{ix}}{z^2+1} dz = \frac{\pi}{e} $$
$$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty \frac {e^{-ix}}{z^2+1} dz = \frac{\pi}{e} $$

The proof is done.

Comment: The Residue Theorem has not been studied yet, so a solution should be possible without it.

Comment: That doesnt matter. The key issue about your analogy is that $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac {sin(t)}{t^2+1} dt \neq 0$ even though $\lim\limits_{R\to\infty} \int_{\Gamma_R} \frac {e^{iz}}{z^2+1} dz=0$

Comment: The Residue Theorem is a very simple theorem about the relation between poles and closed contour integration. Hopefully, you can learn it in several secs.